# How do I use constrOptim to set up a non linear objective function (spillman) with linear inequality constraint?

Tags: r, optimization, linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am trying to maximise a profit function of the form (a-bc^x1)*Py -(Px*X1) 
where a-bc^x1  is a spillman production function (y=a-bc^x1). I convert the production function to a revenue function by multiply the production function with the unit price of commodity expressed as Py.
Px*x1 is the cost function which is  input x1 multiplied by Px; Px is the unit price of  x1.

The above is constrained by a budget of 5000. So Px*X1 <=5000 and X1>=0, 
unit prices Py and Px are 100 and 200 respectively, I rewrite the constraint as 
0<=x1<=25.
I have set up my objective function as below

```
    fn=function(x){
      x1=x[1]
      a=3474;b=1325;c=0.93575;Py=100;Px=200
      -(a-b*(c^x1))*(Py)-(a-b)-(x1*Px)

}
```

My challange come in when coding  ui,ci and theta, which I have made an attempt as follows;

```
A=matrix(c(1,0,-1,0),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
B=c(0,-25)
xinit=c(1,1)
xans2=constrOptim(theta=xinit, f=fn, grad=NULL, ui=A, ci=B,method = "Nelder-Mead")
xans2$par
```

I get an answer of 25.00000, -9.89082 which is strange because I only expect one value for x1. Could someone assist in identifying the problem in my set up?

Answer (score 0):

From `?optim` :

For optim, a list with components:

par:        The best set of parameters found.

value:      The value of fn corresponding to par.

You are asking for `xans2$par` which gives you the best set of parameters found based on what you entered into the function.

`xans2$value` gives the value of `fn` corresponding to those parameters.

If you are looking for a single value, I would guess that this is what you want.

```
xans2$value
[1] -329360
```

Comment: I am using 'ConstrOptim', for the 'xans&pars', I expect a single value since I am only estimating one parameter x1. Please look at my constraint 0<=x1<=25, this should only give one value for x1